# How does the blood flow in the glomerulus when everything except plasma is drained out?

Tags: red-blood-cell, kidney, circulatory-system, renal-physiology, excreta

So I learned that in the glomerulus, everything smaller than the RBCs is filtered out, but I had learned previously that - Blood needs plasma, water medium to flow. So if its drained out into the Bowman's Capsule, how does the blood leave the efferent arteriole.

Could anyone please clarify,
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I'm almost certain that you are misreading (or reading from a source that is in error). Please check this 'fact' with additional sources and then (if this astounding claim is true) update your question to include supporting references to reliable sources (preferably primary literature, but textbooks are acceptable if they are available online). If this is based on someone's misunderstanding/miswriting then please delete your post.

Comment: If it were true (and this is but one small example in the scheme of things) protein, lipids/lipoproteins, and glucose in the urine would be of absolutely no concern.

Comment: Pardon me for my ignorance. So what actually happens? It wasn't explained clearly in my textbooks or on the internet.